# How to search array with first 3 character of its value in php

Tags: php, arrays, search, user-agent

I want to get the browser details of the client. so that am using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to get the details but it get some extra information also like

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36

in chrome browser. what i have done is convert the string into an array like

> Array ( [0] => Mozilla/5.0 [1] => (Windows [2] => NT [3] => 10.0; [4]
>   => Win64; [5] => x64) [6] => AppleWebKit/537.36 [7] => (KHTML, [8] => like [9] => Gecko) [10] => Chrome/60.0.3112.90 [11] => Safari/537.36 )

If i search for Chr -- i want it to search the array and return **Chrome/60.0.3112.90** .

Please suggest solution for this thanks.

Code :

```
echo $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$strArray = explode(' ',$browser);

print_r($strArray);
```

Comment: Thanks B. Desai for the edits

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create function to search from array

```
echo $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$strArray = explode(' ',$browser);

print_r($strArray);
function search_from_array($array,$string)
{
  $return_str = "";
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $pos = stripos($value, $string);
    if($pos !== false)
      $return_str=$value;
  }
  return $return_str;
}

echo search_from_array($strArray,"chr");
```

Comment: This will not work on all cases. OP has requested he needs to be able to search more than just Chrome. If the searchvalue is `win` in this code it will return Win64 and not Windows NT

Answer (score 1):

The way you're converting the user-agent to an array is quite faulty, for example "Windows NT" becomes ['Windows','NT'] and this is not something you want.

You might want to use [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-php) to extract the user-agent information in a better way.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use UAParser\Parser;

$ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Ma...";

$parser = Parser::create();
$result = $parser->parse($ua);

print $result->ua->family;            // Safari
print $result->ua->major;             // 6
print $result->ua->minor;             // 0
print $result->ua->patch;             // 2
print $result->ua->toString();        // Safari 6.0.2
print $result->ua->toVersion();       // 6.0.2

print $result->os->family;            // Mac OS X
print $result->os->major;             // 10
print $result->os->minor;             // 7
print $result->os->patch;             // 5
print $result->os->patchMinor;        // [null]
print $result->os->toString();        // Mac OS X 10.7.5
print $result->os->toVersion();       // 10.7.5

print $result->device->family;        // Other

print $result->toString();            // Safari 6.0.2/Mac OS X 10.7.5
print $result->originalUserAgent;     // Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Ma...
```

Comment: do u have any solution to get like browser : Chrome/60.0.3112.90  and os : win 10 64 bit

Comment: @sabarish is there a need to search for more than chrome? You mention here you need to find OS. Is that also needed? If yes exploding the string is the wrong way to go about it. And the accepted answer will fail unless you add a mountain of code.

Comment: I modified the code to show you how to get OS related information.

Comment: @sabarish in that case you should accept this answer here by Nabil. It's the only answer that will work for multiple searches without a mountain of code. I may be able to build something if I would know what the string looks like in a few examples. But I think Nabils answer is much easier and will probably not fail as easily if something unexpected happens.

Comment: See my new answer below

Answer (score 1):

With the added need for searching for OS that is written in comments the accepted answer will not work well.
@Nabils answer will work quite well but since it splits the string in very small pieces it may be hard to use.

I thought I could use preg_split and create a good array to search and I think I made it.
I don't know all variations of user agents but they seem to follow a pattern.

This will split on space but also on `(` and `)`.

```
$input_line = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36";
$arr = preg_split("/( \()|(\) )/", $input_line);

$arr2 =explode(" ", end($arr)); // explode "Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36" on space
Unset($arr[count($arr)-1]); // remove above exploded
$arr = Array_merge($arr,$arr2); // reinsert them as two items
//Var_dump($arr);

$search = "Chr";

Foreach($arr as $val){
    If($search == Substr($val,0,3)) echo $val;
}
```

See here how it works: https://3v4l.org/qF65g

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex on the string.

```
$str = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36";

$search = "Chr";
Preg_match("/". $search . ".*?\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/", $str, $match);

Var_dump($match);
```

It will capture the search and any characters til / then your digits with dots.

https://3v4l.org/uYpoP