# Strip User Agent PHP

Tags: php

This is my useragent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 4.73) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko)

I want to convert the above to this:

> PlayStation 4 4.73

I've tried a few things like stripping the useragent with substr, but that didn't work out - well, it did but it was slow and didn't look professional at all.

What's the best, smallest and fastest way in PHP to archieve this result?

Comment: What code did you use?

Comment: You need to start by defining rules for what string you want. Is it whatever is in the first parenthesis that are found? What would you want from this UA string: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36`?

Comment: The area in parenthesis is referred to as a comment. Given the format of user agents you can probably just do `preg_split('/[()]/', $userAgent)[1]`. But comments in user agents have no defined structure.

Comment: @PatrickQ it would be for that one particular PS4 useragent, all the other useragents aren't really important

Comment: @cmbuckley That returns "M".

Comment: @Mitch delimiters were missing

Comment: I just deleted my answer since cmbuckley's is much shorter and does the same thing.

Comment: I posted this answer a while ago. It will parse the user agent to each of it's parts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499717/how-to-search-array-with-first-3-character-of-its-value-in-php/45502773#45502773

Comment: @Andreas That is indeed a quite nice piece, however not useful for me as I am specifically looking for the PlayStation 4 useragent, I don't really need to work with the other useragents in my case. The site will be for PS4 browsers only.

Comment: Well In your case you just need the [1] item of the array. It is as you say a overkill for the use you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want "whatever is in the first pair of () brackets"...

```
$str = 'Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 4.73) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko)';
$str = substr($str,strpos($str,'(')+1); // remove the first ( and everything before it
$str = substr($str,0,strpos($str,')')); // remove the first ) and everything after it
echo $str;
```

If you want more complex parsing... (What if there are no brackets, or only one opening/closing bracket? What if the string you want to grab has a ( or ) *in it*? What if you want the contents of the *2nd* brackets, not the first?) then you'll have to do some, uh, programming...

Comment: You know you can make the substring lines in to one line of code?

Comment: I might go with the solution of cmbuckley as that solution is a bit shorter to use.

Comment: @Mitch It may be shorter but also heavier to run. In case you never ever need to look at this code again and never ever need to change it. Here is the one liner I meant Brett should have in his answer. It's as clear as mud. But it works. `$str = substr($str,strpos($str,'(')+1, strpos($str,')')-strpos($str,'(')-1);` This will remove both the stuff before and after in one line. https://3v4l.org/DmNUI

Comment: @Andreas That is true, then I'll probably go with the muddy one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways:

```
// smallest:
$comment = preg_split('/[()]/', $userAgent)[1];

// fastest:
$start = strpos($userAgent, '(') + 1;
$comment = substr($userAgent, $start, strpos($userAgent, ')') - $start));
```